# What does 别间 in 别间大学的男生都土里土气的 mean?

Tags: meaning, word

I've been sentence mining from *Meteor Garden* (2001) and I came across the sentence

> 别间大学的男生都土里土气的。

Can someone help me figure out what does '别间' mean in that sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: It means "other", same as 别的 or 隔壁 but it's not standard Mandarin. It's likely a topolectal term transposed in Mandarin.

Comment: @blackgreen Oh okay I understand, thank you for your help.

Comment: same as "其他"， means "other"

Comment: Please see the answer here https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/where-does-%E5%88%AB%E9%97%B4-other-as-in-%E5%88%AB%E9%97%B4%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6-come-from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does 别间 ("other") as in 别间大学 come from?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/where-does-%e5%88%ab%e9%97%b4-other-as-in-%e5%88%ab%e9%97%b4%e5%a4%a7%e5%ad%a6-come-from)

Answer (score 1):

别 means "not this", in other words, it means "other"

间 is a quantifier for 大学
You need to add a quantifier between 别 and 大学 because you need a quantifier when you count an object

You can also use
别的大学, 别所大学
to express similar meaning

Answer (score 0):

In that particular sentence, it simply means "other".

别 - can have many meaning, when used differently, if it is used only as a single word, it means "dont" or "no", if it is combine with other words, it can have different meaning

间 - can also have many meaning when used differently, it cannot be used as a single word as it could have no meaning, but it can pair with other words to form sentences or meaningful words.

Answer (score 0):

”别间大学的男生都土里土气的“的“间”

As wada rightly wrote, “间 is a quantifier for 大学”

You could write:

其他的大学的男生都土里土气的。
The male students at (all) other universities are all plebeians.